How to automate data point extraction from a graph in ImageJ/Fiji using scripting?
I am working on automating the extraction of data points from a graph in ImageJ/Fiji. I need a script that guides the user through selecting a region of interest (ROI) on the graph, calibrating the axes, detecting the curve, and extracting the data points (e.g., following these instructions). The script can be written in any available scripting language for ImageJ/Fiji (ImageJ Macro Language, JavaScript, Python, etc.).
Desired Workflow:

Activate the Rectangle Tool: Automatically activate the Rectangle tool.
Select ROI: Prompt the user to select the region of interest (ROI) with the Rectangle tool.
Figure Calibration: Activate the "Figure Calibration" plugin to allow the user to calibrate the x- and y-axis.
Remove ROI and Activate Point Tool: Remove the rectangle selection and activate the Point tool.
Select Plot Point and Set Threshold: Prompt the user to select a point on the plot and specify a color threshold for curve detection.
Detect Curve: Detect the curve based on the specified color and sensitivity.
Specify Data Points: Prompt the user to specify the x intervals or the number of points to extract.
Extract Data Points: Automatically place points on the curve and extract the data.
Save Data: Save the extracted data points as a CSV file.

Current Progress:
I have written part of the macro using the ImageJ Macro Language and the "Figure Calibration" plugin, but I am stuck at the point where I need to get the cursor coordinates after the user selects a point on the plot.
Here is the code I have so far:
// Activate the Rectangle tool automatically
setTool("rectangle");

// Step 1: Prompt user to select the region of interest (ROI)
waitForUser("Select the region of interest with the Rectangle tool, then click OK.");

// Step 2: Activate the Figure Calibration plugin
run("Figure Calibration");

// Wait until the calibration window is closed
waitForUser("Set the calibration values in the Figure Calibration window, then click OK.");

// Remove the rectangle selection
run("Select None");

// Activate the Point tool automatically
setTool("point");

// Step 3: Prompt user to select a point on the plot and specify the color threshold
waitForUser("Select a point on the plot and set the threshold for color selection, then click OK.");

// Problematic part
getCursorLoc(x, y);
threshold = getNumber("Enter color threshold for plot detection:", 128);

However, I encounter an error at the getCursorLoc line:
Error: Variable expected in line ...: getCursorLoc ( x , y <)> ; 

Question:
How can I correctly implement this workflow using ImageJ/Fiji scripting? I am open to using any supported scripting language (ImageJ Macro Language, JavaScript, Python, etc.). Specifically, how can I get the cursor coordinates after the user selects a point on the plot and then proceed with curve detection and data extraction?
Any guidance or examples of similar scripts would be greatly appreciated.

Cursor coordinates and point selections are different things!
With the ImageJ macro-language use for …
… Cursor coordinates
getCursorLoc(x, y, z, modifiers);

"Returns the cursor location in pixels and the mouse event modifier flags. The z coordinate is zero for 2D images. For stacks, it is one less than the slice number. Use toScaled(x, y) to scale the coordinates. For examples, see the GetCursorLocDemo and the GetCursorLocDemoTool macros."
… Selection coordinates
getSelectionCoordinates(xpoints, ypoints);

"Returns two arrays containing the X and Y coordinates, in pixels, of the points that define the current selection. See the SelectionCoordinates macro for an example. See also: selectionType, getSelectionBounds."

Thank you for your response. Would you be able to provide additional guidance on how to achieve my goal? I aim to automatically extract data points from a graph based on color thresholds or sensitivity settings.

No idea what "sensitivity settings" means. I think you should be able to do what you want by following my suggestions on Reddit and by using the macro-recorder functionality of ImageJ.

Meanwhile you've received a lot of input that is independent of the programming language or environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78550610/how-can-i-replicate-gimps-select-by-color-tool-in-python-to-extract-data-poin?noredirect=1&lq=1
However, it appears as if you've left the project. Why?

Given your sample graph:
If the text in the graph area of the sample is manually removed, it appears possible to obtain a reasonable result with only very few gaps (NaNs). Below please find a graphical representation of the extracted data values.

For this to work, the graph area must be selected manually by using the rectangle-tool and a point selection must be made on the graph to obtain an estimate of the line color. Below please find a screen-shot of the dialog that illustrates what must be provided to achieve the proper scaling.

